# Mongoose.js - different population than usual

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have the following simplified document from the collection "main":

```
{
    _id: 120,
    name: "Main1",
    prop1: "val",
    menuId: 5
}
```

Here is a simplified document from my "menu" collection:

```
{
    _id: 5,
    menuItems: [an array of elements here],
    menuProperties: {an object here}
}
```

Is it possible to populate with mongoose.js the "menu" document into the "main" document in such way that will result the following model object:

```
{
    _id: 120,
    name: "Main1",
    prop1: "val",
    menuItems: [an array of elements here],
    menuProperties: {an object here}
}
```

What i can achieve now is:

```
{
    _id: 120,
    name: "Main1",
    prop1: "val",
    menuId: {
               menuItems: [an array of elements here],
               menuProperties: {an object here}
            }
}
```

I haven't added the schemes as they are very simple and will contain `ref` for the `menuId`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to remove the `menuId` from population result, and add `menuItem` and `menuProperties` to the population result. Here are the sample codes,

```
Main.find()
    .populate('menuId', 'menuItem menuProperties -_id', 'Menu')
    .exec(function(err, docs){
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            var rets = [];
            docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                // converts the mongoose document into a plain javascript object
                doc = doc.toJSON();
                // add menuItem key
                if (doc.menuId && doc.menuId.menuItem) {
                    doc.menuItem = doc.menuId.menuItem;
                }
                // add menuProperties key
                if (doc.menuId && doc.menuId.menuProperties) {
                    doc.menuProperties = doc.menuId.menuProperties;

                    // remove the menuId object
                    delete doc.menuId
                }
                rets.push(doc);
            });

            console.log(rets);
        }
    });
```

Test with schema

```
var MainSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    prop1: String,
    menuId: Number
});

var MenuSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    menuItem: [String],
    menuProperties: {k: String}
});

var Main = mongoose.model('Main', MainSchema);
var Menu = mongoose.model('Menu', MenuSchema);
```

And results are

```
[ { _id: 56fa39b4924d1254272ac3f1,
    name: 'main1',
    prop1: 'val',
    __v: 0,
    menuItem: [ 't1', 't2' ],
    menuProperties: { k: 'p1' } } ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i think that instead of using `doc.toJSON();` you can add `.lean()` before the `.exec()` call

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.  You could always do something like this (note, you didn't post your schemas so I made up the names):

```
//get every document in menu collection
Menu.find({}).exec(function(err,all_menuItems){

    if (err) {throw err};

    //for all documents in them meny collection
    //find docuement in main collection and update

    all_menuItems.forEach(function(item){

        //wrapping in closure since doing forEach over async function
        function(){

            Main.findOne({_id:item._id}).exec(function(err,mainItem){

            if (err) {throw err};

            //set properties
            mainItem.menuItems = item.menuItems;
            menuItem.menuProperties = item.menuProperties;
            //save document
            Main.save(mainItem)

            })

        }(item)
    })

})
```

Also, mongoose as a built in populate method which can be used to do this.  You can find that documentation here.  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html.

Using populate would probably be a much better option than looping over a bunch of async calls (or re-writing the above code to process the updates synchronously).  But you can handle whatever way makes the most sense for your db.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but i need the `menu` document to be populated into the `main` document. I also need the `menu`'s properties to be at the same level as the `main''s properties

Comment: The above code iterates through all menu documents.  For each menu document it finds the matching main document.  It then populates the main document with the menu document information.  Isn't that what you want?